Can a human not be a natural person?
Unfortunately, UN hasn't done define a human and natural person. Also, can a human not be a person? Is this a basis for exempting a human from the duties of a natural person?

Natural person concept is in contrast to a concept of legal person or legal entity, like a corporation. Human is a legal entity, but a corporation cannot be a natural person. Is that what you are asking about?

No, can a human not be in the status of  the natural person?

What is the context? The U.N. is rarely the source of directly applicable law. And, usually the meaning of legal terms is context specific.

No, humans can never not be natural persons.
The term "Natural Person" is always used for any human, and any human is always a natural person. It is the flip side of a "Legal/judicial Person".
The term "legal person" or "legal entity" is artificial, because it applies to companies, corporations, trusts, and other non-human entities in addition to natural persons. Those non-humans all have rights and duties because they are deemed to have corporate personhood. Without the idea of legal entities, you would not be able to contract with "Amazon AWS" but always need to contract with the company's owner. However, some rights and duties are reserved for natural persons: the law can't ever draft a company into military service, and a company can not marry or have a driver's license.

Some rights are also given to a natural person that legal entities (that are not also natural persons) don't have, like entering into a marriage contract. Corporations cannot get married.

@NeilMeyer good examples, and on the other hand: the draft. The state can not force a company to be part of the military (though the state can disown it or force it to produce war material - but that is not being drafted in the same sense)

a company can not marry — yet...

The problem with your question is that international law fundamentally differs from national law. National law is the law of some sovereign nation, usually with a legislative to pass laws and a judiciary to interpret it. (Even if some of those institutions look unfamiliar to Western eyes.) International law is created by treaties between sovereign nations or by long-established precedent. There can be nations which did not sign some treaty, or which dispute that a point of precedent has become jus cogens.
Most nations accept a definition of "natural person for legal purposes" which includes any living homo sapiens sapiens, but consider that the start of life is hotly debated in many countries, and in some cases also the end of life. So I do not believe that any absolute statement is possible.
For instance, in germany a physician declares the death of a patient and after that the register office fills a form. Death may be declared if brain function is "irretrievably lost" even if the heart is still beating. And there are slightly different legal definitions for the start of a life in criminal and civil law (start of labor vs. leaving the womb).
